# What Does Surjective Functions imply?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

If a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective (don't know anything about injection), does that imply whenever x is in A, then $f(x)$ is in B, that is, $ \forall x \in A, \; f(x) \in B$?

Comment: That's generally the definition of the notation $f : A \to B$. It has nothing to do with surjectivity.

Comment: Well, the definition does require $f(x)$ to be unique as well as in $B$... just to be nit-picky

Comment: each element in the target has preimage

Answer (score 2):

No, that's the definition of a function from $A$ into $B$. That $f(x)\in B$, for every $x\in A$.

Surjectivity means that for every $y\in B$ there exists some $x\in A$, such that $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's true for *any* function by definition! What surjective actually means is that whenever $b\in B$, there exists *some* $x\in A$ with $f(x)=b$.

Answer (score 0):

The surjectivity's definition comply 
$$\forall y\in B\quad \exists x\in A\quad \mbox{such that}\quad  f(x)=y,$$

means *each element in the target-set has preimage in the source-set*.